# Understanding of convergence in probability.

Tags: probability

[image]

I want to study the convergence in probability when $X=0$, then $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=P(|X_n|>\epsilon).$ The thing i don't understand is why is defined by this:

\begin{equation}
  =\begin{cases}
    P(X_n=1-\frac{1}{n})+P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}, & \text{if $\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{n}$}.\\
    P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{2n}, & \text{if $1-\frac{1}{n}\leq \epsilon < 1$}.\\
0, &\text{if $\epsilon\geq 1$},
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Why in the first one is $P(X_n=1-\frac{1}{n})+P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $P(X_n=1-\frac{1}{n})-P(X_n=0)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varepsilon < 1 - \frac{1}{n}$, then the event $\{|X_n| > \varepsilon \}$ can be seen as $\{|X_n| = 1-\frac{1}{n} \} \cup \{|X_n| = 1 \}$.

Then $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|X_n| = 1-\frac{1}{n}) + \mathbb{P}(|X_n| = 1)$ since these events are disjoint.

Comment: Now that makes sense for the next two! Thank you very much i really needed to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because $$1=P(\lvert X_n\rvert >\epsilon)+P(\lvert X_n\rvert<\epsilon)=P(X_n>\epsilon)+P(X_n<\epsilon)=P(X_n>\epsilon)+P(X_n=0)$$ when $\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{n}$.

So, $$P(\lvert X_n\rvert >\epsilon)=1-P(X_n=0)=P(X_n=1-\frac{1}{n})+P(X_n=1)=\frac{1}{n}$$.

I hope this answers your question.